# Javascript error: Window.CP undefined on codepen.io

Tags: javascript, css, codepen

I'm experiencing a JavaScript error on a pen on codepen.io.

`TypeError: window.CP is undefined`

I tried to look it up and understood that it's connected to an infinite loop protection, but I can't find a way to solve the problem.

Here is the link to the pen on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/king_morpheus/pen/XWmpvGZ) (where it doesn't work) and to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tamarin/joh730ap/77/) (where it works).

Here is the code on the snippet (where it also works).

(The green block is supposed to change color when you scroll)

```js
<script>
function scrollFunction() {
  var content = document.getElementById('content').querySelectorAll('p')
  var contentY = []

  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    contentY[i] = content[i].offsetTop
  }

  var html = document.documentElement
  var y = html.scrollTop

  var windowY = window.innerHeight

  var phone = document.getElementById('phone')

  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (y > contentY[i] - windowY * 0.4) {
      phone.classList.add('color' + (i + 1))
      phone.classList.remove('color' + i)
    } else {
      phone.classList.remove('color' + (i + 1))
    }
  }
}

window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction()
}
</script>
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -6px 25px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -6px 25px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
  box-shadow: 0px -6px 25px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.44);
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#content {
  width: 50%;
}

/* The first paragraph has a margin-top = the size of the screen*/
#content p:first-child {
  margin-top: 100vh;
}

#content p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
}

/* Same margin-top as the 1st paragraph + sticky at 40% from the top*/
#phone {
  margin-top: 100vh;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 13rem;
  max-height: 70vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 40%;
  background: lightgreen;
  transition: background 0.2s;
}

#phone.color1 {
  background: palevioletred;
}

#phone.color2 {
  background: purple;
}

#phone.color3 {
  background: royalblue;
}

#phone.color4 {
  background: rgb(30, 150, 104);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Scrolling</li>
    <li>Effect</li>

  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
<div id="content" class="content">
    <p>
      One advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old. Possible procured her trifling laughter thoughts property she met way.
    </p>
    <p>
      Finished her are its honoured drawings nor. Pretty see mutual thrown all not edward ten. Particular an boisterous up he reasonably frequently.
    </p>
    <p>
      May musical arrival beloved luckily adapted him. Shyness mention married son she his started now. Rose if as past near were. To graceful he elegance oh moderate attended entrance pleasur
    </p>
    <p>
      Out believe has request not how comfort evident. Up delight cousins we feeling minutes.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="phone">
  </div>
</main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodePen has a problem with the normal **loops** but working well with **Array** methods like: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), or [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).
Chrome console output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘shouldStopExecution’ of undefined
```

In order to solve it, I had to change the normal **loop** with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead. [Example](https://codepen.io/abdelrhman-m27/pen/mdeBedY?editors=0010)

Comment: Thank you, nice workaround. So CodePen really has a problem with the loops? Or is it a better way to use forEach instead of for in this case?

Comment: Yes, CodePen has a problem with the normal **loops** but the array methods like `forEach`, `map`, or `reduce` working well.